# TopLink JPA children fetch results in many SQL's calls for children

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, toplink

I am having an issue with generated SQL's from a model we built using JPA (TopLink)
We have the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TEST_A")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class TTestA implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "A_ID")
private String id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private D detail;


@OneToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "T_TEST_JOIN", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_FK"),    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
private List<B> childrens;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TEST_B")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class TTestB implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "B_ID")
private String id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private D detail;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TEST_D")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class D implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "D_ID")
private String id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private M moreDetail;
...
}
```

It's basically an one to many using a 3 tables relation. Using the Criteria API, I am able to get the first level and all the One-To-One relations (cascading) and children from A, ie A=>D=>M, in a single SQL using fetch's, but I can't get the children B=>D=>M to act the same.

I end up with a SQL query which gets A, D, M and B, but then multiple queries to get B=>D=>M.

Here is what I do:

```
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<A> c = cb.createQuery(A.class);
    final Root<A> a = c.from(A.class);
    a.fetch(A_.details).fetch(D_.modeDetails);
    a.fetch(A_.childrens);

    ...
```

**Is it possible to "compound" the calls for the children also?**

Answer (score 1):

After much fiddling, I noticed I had another issue also which was that the query would return duplicates.
So I ended up using a.join(A_.childrens, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(B_.details)
And using the query hint 
query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "t1.childrens")
I managed to eliminate the duplicates and fetch the deeper level.